# PostgreSQL failure on test database for Rails application

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, postgis

Upon running `rake db:test:prepare` my test database was dropped, but failed to be rebuilt. After researching the errors, I simply attempted to load the database with `rake db:test:load` to repopulate based on the schema.rb file. That call resulted in the following message

`PG::Error: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

I've spent the day reinstalling postgresql-9.1 and postGIS 1.5.3 on a test server in every way I can find on the internet, and none of those installations produce the ever-elusive postgis.control file. Is there a special install I need to run on a CentOS6 machine to produce the binary? Or is there another way to run the rake tasks to test the psql database?

Comment: I wonder if all I need to do is reload the postgis library into the database, but I'm not sure how. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

This message is shown for `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` however the newer extension method was introduced for PostGIS 2.0. The version that you have installed does not support this method.

Either upgrade to PostGIS 2.0 ([excellent RPMs for YUM here](http://yum.postgresql.org/)), or spatially enable a PostGIS 1.5 database using either a template or using enabler scripts. [Details here](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id418654).

Comment: thanks. I had the same problem. Upgrading to PostGIS 2 fixed it, by providing /usr/.../extension/postgis.control. (using Rails 3.2 on openSuSE 12.3).